# Generics and inline fuctions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have difficulties with generics in Kotlin.
I want to make universal interface and implementation and several type-specific DAOs.

```
// Type parametrized DAO
interface DaoInterface<T : Any> {
    fun <T : Any> getByCollectionId(collectionId: Long, clazz: Class<T>): List<T>
}

//Generic DAO implementation
open class DaoInterfaceImpl<T : Any>(private val entityManager: EntityManager) : DaoInterface<T> {
    override fun <T : Any> getByCollectionId(collectionId: Long, clazz: Class<T>): List<T> =
        entityManager.createQuery(
            "from ${clazz.name} c where c.collectionId = :collectionId", clazz
        )
            .apply { setParameter("collectionId", collectionId) }
            .resultList ?: listOf()

    inline fun <reified T : Any> getByCollectionId(collectionId: Long): List<T> =
        getByCollectionId(collectionId, T::class.java)
}

//Type specified DAO
class TestContactDao(entityManager: EntityManager) : DaoInterface<Contacts>, DaoInterfaceImpl<Contacts>(entityManager)

class Test(private val testContactDao: TestContactDao) {
    fun call() {
        val result1 = testContactDao.getByCollectionId<Contacts>(123L)
        val result2 : List<Contacts> = testContactDao.getByCollectionId(123L)
        val result3 = testContactDao.getByCollectionId(123L)
    }
}
```

result1 and result2 works fine, but in result3 I get "Type inference failed" error.

I don't want to specify generic in theese calls(like in result1 and 2). I want to make several DAO's for different classes(Contacts, Adresses and others) and call them like in result3.

How can i do this?

Comment: What's also strange is that even if you change the `TestContactDao` to `class TestContactDao(entityManager: EntityManager) : DaoInterface<Int>, DaoInterfaceImpl<Int>(entityManager)` for example, then result1 and result2 still compile fine

Comment: @IvoBeckers I think this is because inline fuction ignores DaoInterfaceImpl generic and works with generic in call

Comment: because generic type `T` defined at class level is different from that defined on inline function

Comment: As @sidgate mentioned, `T` in your reified and `T` on your class don't refer to the same type as you redefine `T` in your reified function as a new type variable. Reified inline function *must* know the type when they're called, which is why you need to explicitly define the type in your call.

Comment: @Spitzbueb So, can this be done without reified functions with generics only?  Or I have to implement function in every class specified DAO and pass that class to getByCollectionId(collectionId: Long, clazz: Class<T>)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem ist that your reified `T` does not match the class type `T`, as you redefine that type variable. You can still avoid having to pass a `Class` by defining an extension function on the interface:

```kotlin
// helper extension to simplify access
inline fun <reified T> DaoInterface<T>.getByCollectionId(collectionId: Long): List<T> = getByCollectionId(collectionId, T::class.java)
```

Why does this work? Here we define `T` as reified and specify that `DaoInterface` has to be of the same type `T`.

I have a playground example that's working here: https://pl.kotl.in/kLiM9xD3y